# NuGet debug build process

Tags: visual-studio, nuget

I have a problem with a NuGet build, i.e. I am trying to install OpenCV (2.4.x) and build a sample project. This actually WORKED before but I have done something that causes the build to fail because the lib(s) are not downloaded anymore, even if I create a new project, install the package and press build it does not work.

Now I am quite sure there has to be a way to debug the build process and to figure out what NuGet is doing behind, so I can solve this problem.
But I couldn't find any information about how to do that. How can I step into the build/into the NuGet magic and see where it fails / why it doesn't download the files needed.

So far the only indication is that the linker is missing xy.lib which obviously causes a build fail.

I am using VS 2015 Community with the NuGet Extension!

Thanks for your help and advice!

Comment: What exactly is the failed build message you get?

Comment: I get a linker error because the linker can't find the library (lib) file. NuGet should be download those during the build process

Comment: Problems can be many, as nuget is not so cool with native or mixed projects. I can just give you some directions to think: when you install a package, it is 1. downloaded, 2. project file is modified to include libs\dlls, 3. sometime content is added to project if it was in nuget package. Check if you have libs downloaded and where are they(!). Open project file in notepad and check where are those files added - and if the path is correct.